# Weird result in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Consider the field $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]_{x^2 + x + 1}$. In this field, the polynomial $x^3$ is equal to

$$
\begin{align}
x^3
&\equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} x^3 - x(x^2 + x + 1) \\
&\equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} x^3 - x^3 - x^2 - x \\
&\equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} - x^2 - x \\
&\equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} 4x^2 + x \\
&\equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} (4x^2 + x) - 4(x^2 + x + 1) \\
&\equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} -4 \\
&\equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} 1
\end{align}
$$

however, also $0^3 \equiv_{5} 0$, so this (to be at least, as I think that when stating the equivalence above it holds *for all $x$*) seems to suggest that

$$
0
\equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} 1
$$

however, I do not think this is a true statement, as clearly $1 \ne x^2 + x + 1$ (or any multiple thereof) and $1 \not\equiv_{5} 1$.

I am certain this is a really elementary question which originates from me being really silly (misunderstanding some basic results probably), but I would really appreciate  any clarification/advice on this.

Comment: $x^2+x+1$ divides $x^3-1$  so yes $x^3=1$. Your deduction that $0=1$ is wrong.

Comment: I think your mistake is to treat $x^3$ as a polynomial (which would allow to evaluate it at $x=0$), whereas it is the image of $X$ in the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_5[X]/(X^2+X+1).$ Besides, there are some (harmless since they compensate) mistakes in your calculation. Your calculation could also have been shorter, as hinted by reuns: $x^3\equiv x^3-(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be thinking of $x$ as something like "an unknown element of $\Bbb Z_5$". That's how letters like $x$ behave when you first encounter them in school, and until you start working with quotient rings, there isn't really any indication that this is wrong.

However, in the context of abstract algebra, it is wrong. The symbol $x$ is completely separate from any element in $\Bbb Z_5$. So a relation you encounter that is satisfied by $x$ (such as $x^3\equiv 1$, which you have more or less correctly deduced) will not automatically hold for elements of $\Bbb Z_5$ (such as $0$, which does *not* satisfy $0^3\equiv 1$). Or vice versa.

A more common example of this same effect would use Fermat's little theorem, which tells us that $n^5\equiv n$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z_5$. This does *not* mean that $x^5$ and $x$ are the same polynomials of $\Bbb Z_5[x]$. (The two *polynomial functions* $x\mapsto x^5$ and $x\mapsto x$ from $\Bbb Z_5$ to $\Bbb Z_5$ are the same, but that's a different story.)

Comment: Arthur, "that's a different story" indeed, so your last paragraph might be more  confusing than enlightning.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch You're thinking of polynomials as functions. They are not. There is no mixing of element types here, they are all elements of $\Bbb Z_5[x]_{x^2+x+1}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Is it? Demonstrating a direct contrast between polynomials and polynomial functions, which is the core issue my answer deals with. How would that be confusing?

Comment: Thank you! Would it be correct to say that $x^3 \equiv_{x^2 + x + 1} 1$ just means that the two polynomials have the same remainder when divided, which doesn't necessarily mean that they are the same function?

Comment: @peritremic They aren't functions. But yes, it simply means that as elements of $\Bbb Z_5[x]$, they leave the same remainder when divided by $x^2+x+1$. Equivalently, that their difference is divisible by $x^2+x+1$. Equivalently, that they represent the same element of the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x^2+x+1)$. Equivalently, the two cosets $x^3 + (x^2 + x + 1)$ and $1 + (x^2 + x + 1)$ of the ideal $(x^2 + x + 1)\subseteq \Bbb Z_5[x]$ are equal. I'm sure there are other ways to say it too.

Comment: I think the "core issue" of the question and answer is not the contrast between polynomials and polynomial functions, but between polynomials and elements of a quotient of a polynomial ring by some ideal, so that concentrating on the latter may be clearer for peritremic.

Comment: @AnneBauval Deducing $x^3\equiv 1$ and then applying that to get $0^3\equiv 1$ seems to me very much like confusing polynomials with polynomial functions. But I could be wrong, of course.